# pass the return value of method in return function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native, methods

I want to pass the value(`high`) of the method inside the `return()` function given the code below.

```
renderElement() {
    var high = 0;

    if ( this.state.trends_1[0].start[1] > this.state.trends_1[0].end[1]) {
      high = this.state.trends_1[0].start[1];
    } else {
      high = this.state.trends_1[0].end[1];
    }
    console.log('High: ', high);
    return high;
}
```

I tried to call it, but its just displaying the result in my `console.log`.

```
render() {
  return (
    <Chart id={1} yExtents={[this.renderElement(), 100]} //also tried `this.renderElement`
  );
}
```

Comment: `render() { return(); }` does not return anything

Comment: no, i mean I want to pass the `return` value of the method `renderElement` in my return function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in way also

```
    render() {
      let {trends_1} = this.state
      let high = (trends_1[0].start[1] > trends_1[0].end[1]) 
                 ? trends_1[0].start[1] 
                 : trends_1[0].end[1];
      return(
        ...
        <Chart id={1}
            yExtents={[high, 100]} 
            ...
      );
}
```

```js
// Find the max of values
let trends = [ 
  { start: 3, end: 2 }, 
  { start: 5, end: 1 } 
]

trendValues= [];
trends.map((trend)=> 
  Object.values(trend).map((value)=> 
    trendValues.push(value)
  )
)
console.log("trendValues", trendValues);
let high = Math.max(...trendValues);
console.log("MAX:", high);

// Another Alternative 

function findMax(trends){
  let trendValues= [];
  trends.map((trend)=> trendValues = [...trendValues, ...Object.values(trend)])
  let high2 = Math.max(...trendValues);
  console.log("High2", high2);
}

findMax(trends);
```

Comment: first, thank you for your answer as it really works in me. Just wondering how can I compare say 4 items if I have `start[0]` and `end[0]` as additional, and check the highest value using your code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Added the logic to find the max of all trends value based on your trends Object. This will work of any number of start and end value in trends Object

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
render() {
  const [{ start, end }] = this.state.trends_1;

  return (
    <Chart yExtends={[Math.max(start[1], end[1]), 100]} />
  );
}
```

now you don't have to worry about calling another method in your render. If that doesn't work, you need to check if `start` and `end` are actually located in the array where you assume they are. They might also be `NaN` or something, check for that as well.

Comment: this also works, but since I have 2 set states of the same `start` and `end`, I get duplicate message.